# Check availability of apartments

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in database:

```
apartaments: id_apartmana

reservations: id_rezervacije, check_in, check_out
```

How can I construct a query for when user inputs 2 dates (arrival and departure of tourists) it shows available apartments in that period? I have `if` statement that doesn't do what it is supposed to do:

```
<?php
include_once 'database.php';

$check_in = $_POST['datum1'];
$check_out = $_POST['datum2'];


$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT check_in, check_out, id_apartmana FROM rezervacije");

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ 
if ($_POST['datum1'] < $row['check_in'] && $_POST['datum2'] <= $row['check_in'] or $_POST['datum1'] >= $row['check_out'] && $_POST['datum2'] >= $row['check_out']){
echo $row['id_apartmana'];

} else {
    echo"Apartman nije slobodan :(";
    break;
}
 
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a connection between the `apartaments` table and the `reservations` table. You need to connect the two tables by adding an apartment id to the reservations table, which would link them one-to-many.

Comment: I have foreign key `id_apartmana` in reservations but my problem is that `if` statement  goes through table rows  comparing input dates and check_in and out of one reservation and prints out that apartment is free but its not... How can i make it go through whole table and print actually free apartments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to be sure why your PHP code is not working as you expect as you have not included enough information. There are two obvious potential issues -

1. maybe the dates received via POST are not in the correct format (need to be yyyy-mm-dd) to perform a meaningful comparison.
2. your combinations of ANDs and ORs need parentheses - (condition1 && condition2) or (condition3 && condition4) or (condition5 && condition6)

Even with the above issues resolved, your current code would still be unable to provide the result you are looking for as it is looking at reservations individually.

It would be much more efficient to do these checks in your SQL -

```sql
SET @start = DATE(20220108);
SET @end   = DATE(20220115);
SELECT * FROM apartmana WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM rezervacije
    WHERE rezervacije.id_apartmana = apartmana.id_apartmana AND (
        (check_in < @start AND check_out > @start) OR
        (check_in < @end   AND check_out > @end) OR
        (check_in > @start AND check_out < @end)
    )
);
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8371ca54c67f10f6ed154f926834f744)

Obviously, instead of using the SQL variables you will be using prepared statements.

```php
<?php
include_once 'database.php';

$sql = '
SELECT * FROM apartmana WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM rezervacije
    WHERE rezervacije.id_apartmana = apartmana.id_apartmana AND (
        (check_in < ? AND check_out > ?) OR
        (check_in < ? AND check_out > ?) OR
        (check_in > ? AND check_out < ?)
    )
)';

/* create a prepared statement */
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $check_in, $check_in, $check_out, $check_out, $check_in, $check_out);

$check_in = $_POST['datum1'];
$check_out = $_POST['datum2'];

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have known that. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

What if you checked what reservations you have on selected dates and subtract these rooms from the list of all rooms?

```
SELECT id_rezervacije FROM reservations WHERE check_in BETWEEN date('datum1') AND date('datum2') AND check_out BETWEEN date('datum1') AND date('datum2');
```